# Sort list of tuples by element two of all tuples

Tags: python, sorting, tuples

I want to show the list from the large age to the small age.
 
Here is my list:

```
player = [("Dmitry", 15), ("Dima", 11), ("Sergey", 14), ("Andrey", 12), ("Nikita", 13)]
```

I can sort list using name element by `player.sort` and get this list:

```
[('Andrey',12),('Dima',11),('Dmitry',15),('Nikita',13),('Sergey',14)]
```

But I want this list, where ages are large age to small age:

```
[('Dmitry',15),('Sergey',14),('Nikita',13),('Andrey',12),('Dima',11)]
```

How I can do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve your desired sort by using the **[`itemgetter()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/operator.html#operator.itemgetter)**  function as the **[`key`](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html#key-functions)** parameter and also setting **[`reversed`](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/sorting.html#ascending-and-descending)** to `true` so the list is in decending order:

```
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> players = [("Dmitry", 15), ("Dima", 11), ("Sergey", 14), ("Andrey", 12), ("Nikita", 13)]
>>> players.sort(key=itemgetter(1), reverse=True)
>>> print(players)
[('Dmitry', 15), ('Sergey', 14), ('Nikita', 13), ('Andrey', 12), ('Dima', 11)]
```

Comment: Thank you for giving links. I think I understand this more than other lambda answers

Answer (score 1):

Use `sorted` with `key` and `reverse`

**Ex:**

```
player = [("Dmitry", 15), ("Dima", 11), ("Sergey", 14), ("Andrey", 12), ("Nikita", 13)]
print( sorted(player, key=lambda x: x[1], reverse=True) )
```

**Output:**

```
[('Dmitry', 15), ('Sergey', 14), ('Nikita', 13), ('Andrey', 12), ('Dima', 11)]
```

Comment: I want to use sort not sorted since I want to modify original list.

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass a *lambda expression* as argument for `sorted` method.

```
sorted_list = sorted(player, key=lambda tup: tup[1], reverse=True)
```

**Output**

```
[('Dmitry', 15), ('Sergey', 14), ('Nikita', 13), ('Andrey', 12), ('Dima', 11)]
```

Comment: I want to use sort not sorted since I want to modify original list.

Answer (score 1):

Another way using `lambda` but **without** `reverse=True`:

```
player = [("Dmitry", 15), ("Dima", 11), ("Sergey", 14), ("Andrey", 12), ("Nikita", 13)]
player.sort(key=lambda x: -x[1])

# [('Dmitry', 15), ('Sergey', 14), ('Nikita', 13), ('Andrey', 12), ('Dima', 11)]
```

Comment: I want to use sort not sorted since I want to modify original list.

Comment: @Ramzes666 use `.sort()` then. I will update my answer.